# unzip utf8 to ascii

Tags: linux, utf-8, ascii, unzip

i took some files from linux hosting to my windows via ftp
and when i check file encodings utf8 without bom

now i need to convert those files back to ascii and send my other linux server

i zipped files
can i do something like

unzip if its text file and ut8 format than convert it to ascii

when i am unzipping files , i want to make conversion

thanks ?

Comment: in case when utf8 can be converted to ascii without a loss of information, the utf8 presentation should match the ascii. by design of utf8. otherwise, poorly worded question which (1) I have problems understanding and (2) not related to software development.

Answer (score 6):

The program you're looking for is iconv; it will convert between encodings. Use it like this:

```
iconv -f utf-8 -t ascii < infile > outfile
```

However. ASCII is a subset of UTF-8. That is, a file that's written in ASCII is also correct UTF-8 --- no conversion is needed. The only reason for needing to convert the other way is if there are characters in your UTF-8 file that are outside the ASCII range. And if this is the case, you *can't* convert it to ASCII, because ASCII doesn't have those characters!

Are you sure you mean ASCII? Pure ASCII is rare these days. ISO-8859-15 (Western European) or CP1252 (Windows) are much more common.

Comment: You probably want to use `ascii//TRANSLIT` so that it transliterates unrepresentable characters, rather than just bugging out.